# Restricting Glimpse to Certain IP's?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I'd like to use Glimpse for our prod site, but I want to limit who can turn it on.  This is mentioned 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746444/should-i-deploy-glimpse-to-the-production-site), but currently our site does not have a login, nor is set up for Windows Authentication.  Can I restrict access via IP address?  Also, if I turn glimpse on who will see the results on the page?  Just me or everyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a custom runtime policy. It's actually pretty trivial. Here's a quick and dirty mod to [the sample runtime policy in the Glimpse docs](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Custom-Runtime-Policies) that only allows a particular IP:

```
using Glimpse.AspNet.Extensions;
using Glimpse.Core.Extensibility;

namespace Users.Web.Application.Namespace
{
    public class GlimpseSecurityPolicy:IRuntimePolicy
    {
        public RuntimePolicy Execute(IRuntimePolicyContext policyContext)
        {
            var httpContext = policyContext.GetHttpContext();

            if (httpContext.Request.UserHostAddress == "123.123.123.123")
                return RuntimePolicy.Off;

            return RuntimePolicy.On;
        }

        public RuntimeEvent ExecuteOn
        {
            get { return RuntimeEvent.EndRequest; }
        }
    }
}
```